# Defer properties evaluation in Maven sub-modules

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have some problems trying to run maven in a 3-level multi-module project.

The first level is the super-pom, which defines antrun tasks. It is located in an external repository.
The second one refers to the super-pom, and only include the definition of submodules. Let's say it is in /project
The third level contains the sub-module and its items are located at /project/moduleN.

At the first level, AntRun tasks includes calls to "${project.basedir}".

When I use maven, I go to the second level pom folder and run mvn clean install.

As it only includes sub-modules, it tries to compile them but ${project.basedir} has already been evaluated as being /project, and not /project/moduleN.

I would like to defer the evaluation of those expressions in order to replace them with values from my sub-modules, and not from the pom including them, but I can't find a way to do so.

Here are excerpts from POM files to understand what's going on :

**Super POM**

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>superpom</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <exec dir="${project.basedir}" ...></exec>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Project POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>superpom</artifactId>
</parent>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>projectPom</artifactId>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
</modules>
```

**Modules POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectPom</artifactId>
</parent>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>moduleNPom</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: Maybe we're in need of some POM code. It sounds like your super POM is not so relevant in the discussion. But you're getting me confused about whether you're trying to affect child modules (`moduleN`) during `project` build, or you're trying to affect child modules during their own build. Anyhow, some POM snippets would help me.

Comment: I updated my question to include excerpts from POM files

Comment: Is the antrun plugin contained in the `pluginManagement` section?